# How to query SQLIte to create a View ? More info in the description

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables i.e Item_Details and Item_Qty as shown in the figure. Item_Details contains general details about the item, while Item_Qty contains the qty (There are multiple entries of same Item).

**My Objective**
I want to create a View that contains all the columns from Item_Details as well as an additional column called Qty. This Qty column should contain the sum of all quantities of the particular item from Item_Qty. See the image for clarity. Since I am inexperienced in sqlite, I don't know how to execute such a complex query. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW v_item_qty AS
SELECT
    item_details.Sl_No,
    item_details.Item,
    item_details.Color,
    item_details.Size,
    SUM(item_qty.Qty) AS Qty
FROM item_details
INNER JOIN item_qty ON item_details.Item = item_qty.Item
GROUP BY item_details.Sl_No, item_details.Item, item_details.Color, item_details.Size
ORDER BY item_details.Sl_No;
```

This will create the view to show all the items that have quantity records and aggregates the quantity values. If an Item has no record in the **item_qty** table, it won't appear in this view.

If you need to add items with no quantity records, you need to change **INNER JOIN** to **LEFT JOIN**.

Comment: If suppose the data changes in the Item_Qty, say Qty column is edited in any of the row after the creation of view, does it reflect on the view? I mean to say does View keeps getting updated automatically?

Comment: Yes, whenever you query the view (`select * from v_item_qty`), it will give you the current values. Think about views as pre-written queries. They don't store the data, they always fetch the current data from the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the basics of SQL (and if you do not, there is a wealth of resource on the internet at large),  you need only  break the problem down into bite-sized pieces and you'll see it is not complex at all.

- SELECT: The columns you want in the result. That last column, `Qty`, is the sum of quantities from the `Item_Qty` table. You will need the `SUM` aggregate function, doc found here https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc.
- FROM: The from clause will contain the two tables used in view. Hint: you can alias table names in the FROM clause, which is probably a good idea in this case, since the tables have column names in common. Something like `FROM item_qty iq, item_details id`
- WHERE: This is the clause you will use to tell the query that you want the `Item` column in one table to match the `Item` column in the other table. Something like `WHERE iq.item = id.item`
- GROUP BY: An aggregate function needs a GROUP BY clause if you want "subtotals" by some column. In this case, you want a subtotal by Item, so that's what you would GROUP BY.

I would suggest you work on the query and get the results you want before you do the [`CREATE VIEW {name} as`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) step.